# Need to Zoom in permanently

Tags: linux

I have a notebook with Ubuntu/Linux. When I'm at home I plug it into my 20" monitor that’s hooked up to a switch. Occasionally I need to use it remotely and the screen is so small I need to zoom in numerous times on every page. Is there a way to set "zoom" command into the `.kshrc` so it will automatically be larger? Kinda doubt it but thought I would ask.

Comment: By "zoom in" do you mean change the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

You are not being very clear on what you want zoomed in.

Are we talking the text console resolution or Xorg resolution.

Both resolutions can be changed but in different manners.

### Framebuffer

To change the text console is actually done as kernel option to change the framebuffers VESA mode. This would be usually done in the grub config file if grub is your bootloader. The option is: vga=XXX where XXX is one of the [following](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers) modelines.

On ubuntu check the following [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FrameBuffer) for information on changing the framebuffer.

### Xorg Resolution

To change the xorg resolution there are a few options:

1. Change resolution system wide in the xorg.conf file or on newer systems you add a config file under /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-monitors.conf
2. Most desktop environments allow you to change the resolution through a settings application. IE Gnome, and KDE
3. You can use xrandr in a script to change resolution on xorg start.

#### /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-monitors.conf

```
Section "Monitor"
     Identifier     "DisplayPort-0"
     Option         "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
EndSection
```

#### change-resolution.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 1280x1024
```

Make above file executable and add to autostart on Xorg login.